# The angles of the triangle given the position vectors of the triangle using the scalar product

Tags: vectors, triangles, angle

[image: The question is about finding the angles of the triangle]

I can't seem to show for question (a), I am not sure if it's because of my wrong calculation, or is it the question has the wrong values?

What I have done is I used the scalar product. I found that ${\vec{AB}} = (2,1,5);  \vec{BC}=(2,1,-7)$. Then I tried taking the dot product between the two, and if it is a right-angled triangle, it means there should be two vectors that are perpendicular and that their dot product is $0$.

I have also tried doing that for ${\vec{AC}};\vec{BC}; \vec {BA}; \vec {CA}$ but none of them yielded $0$.

Please advise.

Sorry in advance for any wrong tags and title labelling.

Comment: Your $\vec{BC}=(2,1,7)$ is wrong -- the last component should be $-7$. There may be similar mistakes elsewhere in your computations.

Comment: Sorry @DavidQuinn, I copied my answer wrongly from my paper to the forum. On my paper, despite having -7. I still can't get 0.

Comment: Sorry, @HenningMakholm, I copied my answer wrongly from my paper to the forum. On my paper, despite having -7. I still can't get 0.

Comment: @CCC: What do you get for $\vec{AC}$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm (4,2,-2)

Comment: @CCC: So $\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AC}$ is ...?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, ok. Didn't look into that possibility, because in all the triangles I drew, the A was at the top vertex. Thanks.